# How to split a set of int data to determine the value of the last two digits?

Tags: python

I have a `csv` file that one of the columns called timestamp (in hour and minutes; e.g. 1041 means 10:41).

I want to make sure that the imported data is in the correct format. For example, the program should issue a warning if the data is 1061.

My current idea is to detect the last two digits of the data. If it is greater than 60, an alarm is triggered. What should I do?

Comment: please post your code also

Comment: Code and any necessary data. Please see: [mcve]. Have you tried anything? Why mess with the digits, why not handle it like a time value?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well checking last two digits means finding the remainder after dividing by 100 (modulo operator):

```
num = 1061
min = num % 100 # 61

if min > 60:
  print("Error in minutes by {} minute(s)".format(min % 60))
else:
  print("Success")
```

Without your code there is not much more I can say to help.